# How to change environment variables for a specific vscode folder(workspace)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have more than a couple of compiler that I use. I'm looking for a way to modify the path variables just for a folder(a project where vscode is used). This path should not disturb the user path variables.

host machine : Windows

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: use terminal configurations

Comment: @rioV8, thanks for the suggestion but would that be visible to extensions in vscode?

Comment: then modify the `env` property of the launch config